# Assignment in while loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, netbeans-8

I have strange situation - here is Javascript code - and in NetBeans IDE 8.0 I see an alert "Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment":

```
var elem;
var a = 0;
while ((elem = document.getElementById('id-' + a)) !== null) {
    //Some code
    a++;
}
```

[image]

But code works fine. Maybe this is some bug in Netbeans IDE 8.0?

Answer (score 9):

The code is fine. The IDE's warning is because *usually* a comparison (`==`) is made, but sometimes an assignment (`=`) is what is actually wanted. It's to catch mistakes made by missing an equals sign.

Here, you set the `elem` variable, and at the same time, compare it to null.

Comment: Also worth noting that the null check is redundant with `getElementById`, it's just there for the benefit of the reader

Comment: If I use `!=` then I get additional warning: Expected "!=="  and instead saw "!="

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis I guess it's being very strict about what is allowed. `!=` is valid.